# Словообразование - новые слова

Tags: словообразование

Назовите последние десять слов, которые вошли в русский язык посредством словообразования.

**Обновление**

Покопавшись в инете, нашёл вот это:

```
блог
бэйдж, бэдж
виртуал
капоэра, капоэйра
мундиаль
снэки
спам
файер
флешмобер
```

Comment: А каких именно десяти слов идет речь?


Answer (score 2):

То, что появляется само, мне редко нравится. Хочется внести слово от себя. Не хватает его для обозначения людей, пишущих изощрённые сценарии политических событий. Почему возникло такое желание? Несколько лет назад был американский фильм с Дастином Хоффманом и Робертом де Ниро (и ещё он примечателен музыкой Марка Нофлера). Не помню его прокатного названия, но он был показан по одному из центральных каналов. Сюжет в жанре "чёрной комедии" был такой: киносценаристам за хорошие деньги предложили написать сценарий мистификации - для показа по телевидению кадров несуществующих беспорядков в далёкой стране, чтобы в глазах обывателя оправдать планируемое военное вторжение. В оригинале фильм назывался 'Wag the Dog' (букв. "хвост виляет собакой" или "раскрутить пса за хвост"). Примечательно, что вслед за фильмом в мире стали происходить события, будто спланированные по его сценарию (начиная с событий в тогдашней Югославии), и местами они продолжают происходить до сих пор - как по фильму. Мне пришло в голову английское определение для таких "сценаристов": DOGWAGGER. Проверил гуглом - слово действительно стало употребляться в английском, и думаю, благодаря фильму. Так что моё предложение: ДОГВЕГГЕР (наёмный сочинитель опасных сценариев). Ничем не хуже "диггеров" с "киллерами". И не понимаю, почему нет такого красивого и аппетитного слова как СЁМБУРГЕР - давно-давно его придумал. Есть слово - появится и блюдо, хотя бы домашнее и хотя бы у кого-то.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!
Очень часто слова и мысли переплетаются, образуя некую замысловатую канву... И то, что мы говорим и о чём думаем - сбывается наяву, как по мановению волшебной палочки! Я с этим сталкивался и не раз!
Так что - Наши слова - это наше будущее!!!